# Is WPF adequate for creating such a form or am I missing something?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

**Intro:**

> I am quite new to C#.
>   It is my job to create a certain simulation program.
>   I can't ask other programers, I'm an intern with a nonprogramer adviser and should not nother them. (I'm doing more of a fun project.)
>   So before spending a week or two to get really into WPF, I wanted to make sure it fits my needs. 
>   If not, I want to use something else.

**What I need:**

1. Show the user a range of radio buttons to decide wether a simulation/plot/opening_of_svg should be done or not. (Can be done.)
2. A button "Add Task" where the user can choose one. (Can be done.)
3. Depending on the choice, add a certain form into the existing one, where parameters can be set. (*Not found.*)

   1. Some of them radio buttons. (Can be done.)
   2. Some of them text box, for integers and doubles only. (Can be done.)
   3. All of them with default values. (Can be done.)
4. After adding a task, another "Add Task" button should be created, for adding more of them. (*Not found.*)
5. If for example a second simulation is added, it should take the values of the first one as default. (Can be done.)
6. Save the choices and data to a text file in a certain syntax like "Gnuplot Add Restriction = Time" which is used by the rest of the program. (*Can probably be done.*)

**Question:**
The biggest uncertainty is the one with adding forms into the forms.
Can this be done in WPF?
If there is any other framework (if this is the right name) specially made for this, feel free to comment.

> I can't add many links due to my reputation. I might do it later. Just in case someone will find this later and wants to know about how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating `Form`s, consider creating [`UserControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s and arranging them within a single [`Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is the same pattern you might use when creating composite windows in WinForms. I'd recommend the [`Grid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DockPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) layout panels.

In this respect, WPF is quite similar.

In addition, it sounds to me like you are doing a feasibility study for a new requirement. Are you sure it is not appropriate to speak to more senior staff? If I was them, I'd want to know your findings!

### On reflection...

It seems like you are trying to create a branching Wizard workflow, like an installer might give you, i.e. Next, Next, I Agree, Next, Finish. WPF Can absolutely do this and some open source solutions already exist. For example, [Avalon Wizard](https://avalonwizard.codeplex.com/).

Comment: As I'm new to the topic, I don't know the differences between Form and UserControl. Or any of the names at all. I study the 1D modell and the company is building a program for 2D. It is mostly the curiosity of my advisor.

Comment: "On reflection...": It should stay in the same window, not switch between them. So you can change parameters after adding all tasks.

Comment: I've added some links to the classes I reference. Click them and go to the Remarks section to find out more. You will absolutely need to know these terms if you want to advance with wpf. Don't be afraid to Google-and-Pray. There is lots of good advice out there - "how should i use a usercontrol? wpf" etc.